# Split string in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a string like "Hi I am from "Kazan, Russia". The output should be

```
Hi
I
am
from
Kazan, Russia
```

I tried the regex `[^\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'`, which works fine on [regexp.com](http://www.regexpal.com/). But in dataweave it does nothing.
This is what I tried

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%function split(data) {returnData: data splitBy "[^\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'"}
---
split(payload)[0]
```

**Edit 1**

I tried **scan** operator
This is what I did

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
payload: payload scan /[^\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'/
}
```

But I am getting `NullPointerException`
**Stack trace**

```
Message               : null (java.lang.NullPointerException).
Payload               :      com.mulesoft.weave.reader.DefaultSeekableStream@5d334a28
Element               : /logFlow/processors/0 @ log:log.xml:14 (Transform Message)
Element XML           : <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="87d4353c-240d-4b1c-84b4-171f6c11045b">
                    <dw:input-payload mimeType="plain/text"></dw:input-payload>
                    <dw:set-payload>%dw 1.0%output application/json---{payload: payload scan /[^\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'/}</dw:set-payload>
                    </dw:transform-message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the syntax you have used in your initial query, but the following should work for the payloads with the following formats:

```
Hello I am from "Kazan, Russia"
```

and:

```
Hello I am from "Kazan, Russia
```

The below sample uses:

1. [Possessive Quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that match on the required word characters.
2. An explicit match on `,` to help match the location.
3. [Reduce](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-reference-documentation#reduce) the output from an array.

DataWeave:

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
%var data =  "Hello I am from \"StackOverflow, Internet\""
---
data scan /\w++, \w++|\w++/ reduce ($$ ++ $)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the regex part, what `\w++, \w++|w++` does? I know `\w` will match non word character but not getting the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Referring DataWeave documentation, Regular Expressions are defined between **/**. Therefore, replace the double quote **"** with **/**. So it should be like this: `/[^\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'/`

Another thing is, **splitBy** splits a string into an array of separate elements. So you will not get the expected result. Indeed, the payload will be split to 5 elements, but its content is empty. For example: `"a,b,c" splitBy ","` returns 3 elements: "a" - "b" - "c", the comma/separator is not part of the result.

To get the expected result, try to use **scan**. It returns an array with all of the matches in the given string. Might be you should modify the regex accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

`%dw 2.0`

### %output application/json

payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    accountType: payload01.accountType,
    address: payload01.street ++ payload01.city,
    country: payload01.country,
    creationDate: payload01.creationDate as :string,
    firstName: (payload01.name splitBy ' ')[0],
    id: payload01.accountID,
    lastName: (payload01.name splitBy ' ')[1],
    miles: payload01.miles,
    postal: payload01.postal
})

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression

%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var splittedValue='Hi I am from Kazan, Russia' //splitBy " "

---

splittedValue splitBy " "

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this in dataweave by my making a userdefine function that calls splitBy() function
In the code below I'm parsing the name return from db in firstname and last name

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun split(data) = data splitBy (" ")
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    id: payload01.accountID default "",
    address: ((payload01.street default "") ++ (payload01.city default "")) ++ (payload01.state default ""),
    postal: payload01.postal default "",
    country: payload01.country default "",
    creationDate: payload01.creationDate as String default "",
    accountType: payload01.accountType default "",
    firstName: split(payload01.name)[0],
    lastName: split(payload01.name)[1],
    miles: payload01.miles default 0
}
```